# iOS In App Purchase Receipt Duplicate Management

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

When building In App Purchases into an iOS app, Apple gives you access to a receipt that you can send to your server to view all In App Purchase transactions for that given iTunes user related to your application.

If in my application I require users to login or create an account through my system before making a purchase, how can I guarantee that iTunes receipt will not be duplicated?

For example, if a user makes a purchase, the application sends the user ID, and iTunes receipt to my server. The server then stores that receipt along with the user ID in a database. The next time the server wants to check the users purchases we can retrieve all the receipts for that given user ID out of the database and run checks on it.

But if the user logs out and logs in as a different user and makes another purchase the receipt will be sent to the server again, with a different user ID. Effectively, allowing 1 purchase to be used on unlimited user accounts.

Due to the fact that the receipts change over time (auto renewing subscriptions, etc), I don't think it's safe to rely on the receipt being the same every time it's sent to my server and using the receipt data as a unique identifier.

I also considered storing the `original_transaction_id` for one of the transactions, but I don't think that would work since an application might have multiple non-consumable items, or multiple subscriptions, therefor there might be multiple completely valid `original_transaction_id`'s in one receipt. So it doesn't really associate that receipt, but just the transaction.

Ideally, I'd like a system where when a user logs out, and logs in (as a different user or same), the application will send the receipt to the server, and dissociate any of the same receipts for all existing users, and link this new receipt to the user that logged in. Problem is, it doesn't look like there is any type of unique identifier for a given receipt that I can use to check for duplicate receipts in my system.

What is the best way to detect duplicate receipts sent to my server (so I can dissociate the old receipts accordingly)?

---

PS. I think this system is most important for subscriptions, and non-consumable items. For consumable items it will always have to be linked to 1 specific user, and I can just store the `transaction_id` and `original_transaction_id` for that consumable item to ensure it doesn't get duplicated.

Comment: You can't look at the receipt as a whole.  You need to look at the individual transactions. Presuming you don't need to provide access to prior periodic content and you are only interested in whether the user has an active subscription "now" you need to store the latest transaction Id and the expiration date of that transaction against the user. As the subscription renews, update the data stored against the user. If you see the same transaction presented for a different user you can take whichever action you prefer.

Comment: For consumable and non-consumable you just store the original transaction Id and product code against the user